# Создание php файла в теме wordpress через админку

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, как создать php файл в теме wordpress через админку.

Закинуть файлы при помощи ftp на хостинг нет возможности.

Comment: Хороший вопрос, а как Вы создаете php файл при написании программы?

Comment: обычно я создаю файл через редактор и закидываю через ftp, но проблема в том что его у меня нету(ftp)

Comment: Кого нету?......

Comment: Создайте файл программно, кодом в functions.php

Comment: если не сложно напишите пример кода для создания страницы

Comment: как пример можно почитать тут https://wp-kama.ru/id_5177/3-sposoba-sozdat-shablon-stranitsyi.html

Comment: Задача слишком общего характера, например можно установить плагин по типу файл менеджера. Вот один из таких плагинов https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/file-manager/

Answer (score 0):

touch('wp-content/themes/theme_name/template.php');